# Compactar arquivos JS externos

Tags: javascript, pagespeed-insights

No `PageSpeed` do Google, alguns warnings que as vezes recebo, é para ativar a compactação de arquivos JS e CSS. Mas, como trabalho com APIs e scripts externos, as vezes não tem como fazer isso.

- **Teria como contornar esse "problema" de algum jeito?**

Compactando o arquivo externo, ou, dentro da chamada dele no meu site.

- **fazer alguma coisa pra ele ficar "mais leve"?**

Comment: Por que você não pode baixa-los e deixar no projeto?

Comment: Porque por exemplo, atualizações, se eu baixar, terei que ficar baixando toda hora que for atualizado, outra coisa é que, nesse projeto que estou, não tenho acesso ao codigo fonte, somente posso editar html, css, javascript, etc...

Comment: Entendi. Não conheço (e acredito) que não tenha compactar recursos js externos, porque você está sendo cliente. Ou você teria que chamar algum minificado e/ou compactado ou baixar e trabalhar ele. O ideal é baixar, mesmo com as atualizações, na verdade imagino que no maximo verificar uma vez ao dia.

Comment: O [Javascript Minifier](https://javascript-minifier.com/) possui uma API que você pode realizar a compressão. Ela não te ajuda?

Comment: Acredito que esse cara faça mais ou menos o que o Gulp faz @bio, não minifica em tempo de download um recurso externo.

Comment: @LucasCosta acho que sim, [este link](https://javascript-minifier.com/php) tem um exemplo de como fazer a compressão em tempo real com o PHP. Mais abaixo tem uma biblioteca que um usuário criou para fazer isso, testei e funcionou com o jQuery. Ela faz a compressão em tempo real e grava o arquivo compressado em uma pasta do projeto. O único problema que notei é que a compressão ficou bem demorada.

Comment: Ja tentou fazer chamadas assincronas pra esses arquivos?

Comment: Darley, pesquisando, quando faço essas chamadas, ele vai carregar o arquivo JS somente depois do site carregado? Não entendi muito bem.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o [**PHP-JS-CSS-Minifier**](https://github.com/promatik/PHP-JS-CSS-Minifier), ela é uma biblioteca em PHP que faz a compressão de arquivos javascript e css em tempo real e salva em uma pasta do projeto.

Ele utiliza como base a API do site [Javascript Minifier](http://javascript-minifier.com/php). Basta você incluir os códigos como no exemplo:

```
include_once("minifier.php");

$js = array(
    "js/application.js"     => "js/application.min.js",
    "js/main.js"            => "js/main.min.js"
);

$css = array(
    "css/application.css"   => "css/application.min.css",
    "css/main.css"          => "css/main.min.css"
);

minifyJS($js);
minifyCSS($css);
```

Testei com o plugin jQuery através da url deles `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js` e funcionou como esperado:

```
include_once("minifier.php");

$js = array(
    "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"   => "js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
);

minifyJS($js);
```

A desvantagem é que, como a compressão é feita em tempo real, a requisição se torna lenta e acaba não sendo uma vantagem colocar diretamente no corpo da página do seu site, uma vez que toda vez ele realizará essa compressão. Uma saída seria inserir um `if` antes de iniciar a compressão e comparar a data dos dois arquivos para verificar se seu script se encontra atualizado.